# Is there a way to print a calculated time format string in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, time, datetime-format

I know the title might be confusing, but I'm not sure how to word it better....

I'm doing this to get the logs of the current hour:

```
'TraceSink-'yyyy-MM-dd HH'-Hourly.log'
```

How can I get the previous hour? i.e.:

```
'TraceSink-'yyyy-MM-dd (HH-1)'-Hourly.log'
```

Is there anything possible with time format like that?

**EDIT**: I don't have access to the C# code but a exe.config where I can change what goes inside.

Like var on DateTime.ToString(var);

Am I asking too much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is **no**.

The format string only defines the format. It does not have the ability to perform calculation on it (and why would it?)

Comment: Probably dreaming too much about it. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 8):

Subtract one hour from the date/time and format *that*.

Comment: `String.Format("TraceSink-{0}-Hourly.log", someDateTime.AddHours(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH"));`

Comment: @ChaseFlorell: You can specify the format for the DateTime in the format string - no need to call ToString separately.

Comment: I only have access to a variable that goes inside the ToString function. Like var on DateTime.ToString(var); -Maybe I'm asking too much?

Comment: You are asking for things you can't do with a forat string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have this requirement, but I suspect that you may be receiving DateTime objects from a machine in another time zone... it could be helpful if you included the offset from UTC in your format string:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#zSpecifier

This way, when you see the log you can tell that the specific event occurred at UTC -3 hours.

I think that's the best you can do without access to the original code.